# Toggling between clicked elements

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

I have a row of images, when the user clicks on an image then that image is selected. How can I manage to toggle the click event in jquery so that:

1) Only one image can be selected at a time 
2) If the selected image is clicked on then it is deselected.

Here's what I have so far, with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/BY9Fp/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectedTile = null;

    $('[id^="tile-"]').click(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "red");
            $(this).css("opacity", "0.4");
            selectedTile = $(this).attr("name");
            console.log(selectedTile);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the styles into a CSS class as follows:

```
.tile_wrap.selected {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

And then make your click handler something like:

```
var tiles = $('.tile_wrap');
$('[id^="tile-"]').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else
    {
        tiles.removeClass('selected');    
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        selectedTile = $(this).attr("name");
        console.log(selectedTile);
    }
});
```

You can see the updated [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BY9Fp/9/).

Comment: Thanks. I've updated your answer to deselect a tile as well. http://jsfiddle.net/jamiefearon/BY9Fp/16/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.siblings()`

```
         $(this).siblings().css({background:"",opacity:1});
        $(this).css({"background": "red","opacity":"0.4"});
```

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/BY9Fp/11/

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of your code:

```
var $tiles = $('.tile_wrap');
$tiles.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $tiles.not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Improvements making your code simplier and more efficient:

- Cache frequently used elements, e.g. `$titles`;
- Select elements by `class` instead of `[id^="tile-"]`, this will be more efficient;
- Don't use `css` method. Use `addClass` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/BY9Fp/8/

Comment: Just a note on point two. There might other elements on the page with the same classname that he does not want to select.

Comment: @BenM Obviously he should use class specific class name for this specific task. Doing things like `[id^="tile-"]` is bad, bad practice.

Comment: I agree with you, but just thought that I'd point out there may be another reason for his approach here.

Comment: The only reason I can think when using such selectors is reasonable, is when developer don't have access to HTML and can't add class names. Well also when developer wants to make his code work slower..

Comment: The id of each element is created on the fly from the server. Would you suggest using instead of id^="tile-"